# Format a string to be used as an anchor tag (# bookmark) and set as the ID attibute of a HTML element

Tags: c#

I need to convert strings with non-url safe characters (examples include ', ", & and accented letters in spanish / french / german) into a format that will work as an anchor in a URL

e.g. www.site.com#**anchor**

I have tried HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(s) and HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s) - they work as billed but they do not result in an anchor string that actually works correctly (testing in Firefox)

At the moment I am replacing out the offending characters to get it to work but I thought there must be a more generic method to use for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You would use both. First you encode the anchor so that it works in the URL, then you encode the entire URL so that it works in an HTML attribute:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("http://www.site.com#" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s))
```